# My div background image doesn't shown

Tags: css, html

I assigned a background image for a `<div>` in the CSS of my HTML code, i assigned the width and height and also add contents to the `<div>` but the bg still not shown, this is what I've tried:

**CSS:**

```
  #order_list {
    position: absolute;
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 75%;
    top: 35px;
    color: #F33;
    background:url(img/ItemList.png)
    display: inline-block;
    alignment-adjust: central;
    font: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-size-adjust: inherit;
    grid-rows: inherit;
    list-style: upper-alpha;
    word-spacing: inherit;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    vertical-align: central;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="order_list">
<div id="confirm" class="buttonClass">
  <div align="center">Confirm</div>
</div>    

<div id="total" class="totalClass">
  <div align="center"></div>
</div>  
  </div>
```

**screen shot:**
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It might depend on how your browser interprets it, but you forgot a semicolon at the end of

`background:url(img/ItemList.png)`

Without it, browsers won't show the image. Thanks to @Leeish for noting that in this case, a semicolon is absolutely neccessary.

Comment: ; is required except for the last item in a list of style declarations. So yes, he needs it.

Answer (score 2):

`;` is missing at the end of `background:url(img/ItemList.png)` which is why you are not getting the background image.

Semicolon is needed to separate the declarations from one another. 
It can be omitted from the last declaration in a CSS rule, but it is recommended so that later if you want to add more declarations, you won’t need to remember to add it in there.